# Can a subtraction between two exactly represented floating point numbers with the same exponent be inexact?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have 2 numbers, x and y, that are known and are represented exactly as floating point numbers. I want to know if z = x - y is always exact or if rounding errors can occur. For simple examples it's obvious:

```
x = 0.75 = (1 + 0.5) * 2^-1
y = 0.5 = 1 * 2^-1
z = x - y = 0.25 = 0.5 * 2^-1 = 1 * 2^-2
```

But what if I have x and y such that *all* significant digits are used and they have the same exponent? My intuition tells me the result should be exact, but I would like to see some kind of proof for this. Is it different if the result is negative?

Comment: Your question title and description do not match. In particular - if the exponent is the same, then subtraction should be exact (no proof - maybe there can be exist some border cases, when this is not true); if exponent is not the same, then generally not.

Comment: If exponent and sign are the same, the subtraction will be exact. If the signs are different the magnitudes are added, and there can be a carry from the most significant bit position. A one in the least significant bit position would result in rounding and an inexact result.

Comment: @Arvo: I assume you mean that my "simple example" and the title doesn't match? Good point though, I will edit the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the two numbers to have the same sign.  If not, the answer is "yes"; consider `(-1) - nextafter(1, infinity)`, which works out to `-2` in floating-point arithmetic with round-to-even.

Under this assumption, the answer is "no."  This is (almost) a special case of Sterbenz's theorem:  If `x` and `y` are floating-point numbers of opposite signs such that `|y|/2 <= x <= 2|y|`, then `x + y` is exactly-representable as a floating-point number.

I say "almost" because your statement also works for zero and subnormal numbers.

Comment: Sterbenz's theorem is also known as Sterbenz's lemma in the literature.